# Modified Pre-order Tree Traversal, Retrieve only n levels deep?

Tags: mysql, tree, treeview

I've just started working with this algorithm, it really is a great method. The only thing I'm stuck on is how could I retrieve only n number of levels deep in the tree, for example...

[image: Tree Traversal]

*Img src = http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/ (Great Article)*

In the diagram above, how could I select all children of Food, but only 2 levels deep into the tree (Would be everything except cherry and banana).

**You only need answer with pseudo code, but you can with MySQL if you like.**

My current SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT `treeItems`.`ID` AS `treeItemsID`, `treeItems`.`parent`, `treeItems`.`type`

FROM 
       `treeItems`,
       (
           SELECT `lft`, `rgt` FROM `treeItems` WHERE `ID` = $parent

       ) AS `parentRow`

WHERE  `treeItems`.`lft` > `parentRow`.`lft` AND `treeItems`.`lft` < `parentRow`.`rgt`
```

Comment: Add an additional column that stores each record's depth in the tree, then you merely need add to your `WHERE` clause `AND treeItems.depth <= 2`.

Comment: @eggyal : I was hoping I could do it only with the left & right values, adding the additional column would be an extra overhead to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

I found another similar question on SO: [Modified preorder tree traversal: Selecting nodes 1 level deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661913/modified-preorder-tree-traversal-selecting-nodes-1-level-deep) , this helped me to solve it.

So, I changed my SQL to:

```
SELECT `treeItems`.*, (COUNT(`depthJoin`.`ID`) - 1) AS `depth`
FROM   `treeItems`,

       (
       SELECT `lft`, `rgt` FROM `treeItems` WHERE `ID` = $parent

       ) AS `parentRow`

CROSS JOIN `treeItems` AS `depthJoin`

WHERE (`treeItems`.`lft` BETWEEN `depthJoin`.`lft` AND `depthJoin`.`rgt`)
AND   (`treeItems`.`lft` > `parentRow`.`lft` AND `treeItems`.`lft` < `parentRow`.`rgt`)

GROUP BY `treeItems`.`ID`
HAVING `depth` <= $maxDepth
```